# Android get date before 7 days (one week)

Tags: java, android, date

How to get date before one week from now in android in this format:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

ex: now `2010-09-19 HH:mm:ss`, before one week `2010-09-12 HH:mm:ss`

Thanks

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Parse the date:

```
Date myDate = dateFormat.parse(dateString);
```

And then either figure out how many milliseconds you need to subtract:

```
Date newDate = new Date(myDate.getTime() - 604800000L); // 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
```

Or use the API provided by the `java.util.Calendar` class:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(myDate);
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -7);
Date newDate = calendar.getTime();
```

Then, if you need to, convert it back to a String:

```
String date = dateFormat.format(newDate);
```

Comment: I think the opposite is true: roll() does not handle month/year changes when called on the date, while add() does.

Answer (score 26):

I have created my own function that may helpful to get Next/Previous date from

**Current Date:**

```
/**
 * Pass your date format and no of days for minus from current 
 * If you want to get previous date then pass days with minus sign
 * else you can pass as it is for next date
 * @param dateFormat
 * @param days
 * @return Calculated Date
 */
public static String getCalculatedDate(String dateFormat, int days) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, days);
    return s.format(new Date(cal.getTimeInMillis()));
}
```

**Example:**

```
getCalculatedDate("dd-MM-yyyy", -10); // It will gives you date before 10 days from current date

getCalculatedDate("dd-MM-yyyy", 10);  // It will gives you date after 10 days from current date
```

and if you want to get Calculated Date with passing **Your own date:**

```
public static String getCalculatedDate(String date, String dateFormat, int days) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, days);
    try {
        return s.format(new Date(s.parse(date).getTime()));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.e("TAG", "Error in Parsing Date : " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
```

**Example with Passing own date:**

```
getCalculatedDate("01-01-2015", "dd-MM-yyyy", -10); // It will gives you date before 10 days from given date

getCalculatedDate("01-01-2015", "dd-MM-yyyy", 10);  // It will gives you date after 10 days from given date
```

Comment: Wow.. great answer. Looking for this only.

Comment: second function should return `s.format(cal.getTime())`

Answer (score 8):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate
    .now( ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) )           // Get the date-only value for the current moment in a specified time zone.
    .minusWeeks( 1 )                                  // Go back in time one week.
    .atStartOfDay( ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) )  // Determine the first moment of the day for that date in the specified time zone.
    .format( DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME )  // Generate a string in standard ISO 8601 format.
    .replace( "T" , " " )                             // Replace the standard "T" separating date portion from time-of-day portion with a SPACE character.
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses the java.time classes.

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.forID( "America/Montreal" ) ;
LocalDate now = LocalDate.now ( z ) ;
```

Do some math using the `minus…` and `plus…` methods.

```
LocalDate weekAgo = now.minusWeeks( 1 );
```

Let java.time determine the first moment of the day for your desired time zone. Do not assume the day starts at `00:00:00`. Anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time means the day may start at another time-of-day such as `01:00:00`.

```
ZonedDateTime weekAgoStart = weekAgo.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

Generate a string representing this `ZonedDateTime` object using a `DateTimeFormatter` object. Search Stack Overflow for many more discussions on this class.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME ;
String output = weekAgoStart.format( f ) ;
```

That standard format is close to what you want, but has a `T` in the middle where you want a SPACE. So substitute SPACE for `T`.

```
output = output.replace( "T" , " " ) ;
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

## Joda-Time

**Update:** The Joda-Time project is now in maintenance mode. The team advises migration to the java.time classes.

Using the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library makes date-time work much easier.

Note the use of a time zone. If omitted, you are working in UTC or the JVM's current default time zone.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now ( DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" ) ) ;
DateTime weekAgo = now.minusWeeks( 1 );
DateTime weekAgoStart = weekAgo.withTimeAtStartOfDay();
```

Answer (score 4):

## Try this

One single method for getting the date from current or bypassing
any date

*@Pratik Butani's second method for getting the date from our own date is not working at my end.*

**Kotlin**

```
fun getCalculatedDate(date: String, dateFormat: String, days: Int): String {
    val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
    val s = SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat)
    if (date.isNotEmpty()) {
        cal.time = s.parse(date)
    }
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, days)
    return s.format(Date(cal.timeInMillis))
}
```

**Java**

```
 public static String getCalculatedDate(String date,String dateFormat, int days) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
    if (!date.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            cal.setTime(s.parse(date));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, days);
    return s.format(new Date(cal.getTimeInMillis()));
}
```

## Usage

1. getCalculatedDate("", "yyyy-MM-dd", -2) // If you want date from today
2. getCalculatedDate("2019-11-05", "yyyy-MM-dd", -2) // If you want date from your own

Comment: These terrible date-time classes were supplanted years ago by the industry-leading *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Answer (score 1):

I can see two ways:

1. Use a [GregorianCalendar](http://d.android.com/reference/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html):

   ```
   Calendar someDate = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
   someDate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -7);
   SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
   String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(someDate);
   ```
2. Use a [android.text.format.Time](http://d.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html):

   ```
   long yourDateMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() - (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
   Time yourDate = new Time();
   yourDate.set(yourDateMillis);
   String formattedDate = yourDate.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");
   ```

Solution 1 is the "official" java way, but using a GregorianCalendar can have serious performance issues so Android engineers have added the android.text.format.Time object to fix this.

Comment: The roll method doesn't affect any other fields, so you'll always be stuck in the same month, even if you try to go back 7 days from the first of the month.

Comment: You're right, I fixed the example. Anyway, my point was more on the usage of android.text.format.Time which is preferred if you are updating a date in a ListView item. Using GregorianCalendar could prevent your list from scrolling really fast.

Comment: Thankyou, note fellow programmers the first example here should format (someDate.getTime()) rather than just someDate

Comment: Time is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code for get exact string which you want.

```
object DateUtil{
    fun timeAgo(context: Context, time_ago: Long): String {
        val curTime = Calendar.getInstance().timeInMillis / 1000
        val timeElapsed = curTime - (time_ago / 1000)
        val minutes = (timeElapsed / 60).toFloat().roundToInt()
        val hours = (timeElapsed / 3600).toFloat().roundToInt()
        val days = (timeElapsed / 86400).toFloat().roundToInt()
        val weeks = (timeElapsed / 604800).toFloat().roundToInt()
        val months = (timeElapsed / 2600640).toFloat().roundToInt()
        val years = (timeElapsed / 31207680).toFloat().roundToInt()

        // Seconds
        return when {
            timeElapsed <= 60 -> context.getString(R.string.just_now)
            minutes <= 60 -> when (minutes) {
                1 -> context.getString(R.string.x_minute_ago, minutes)
                else -> context.getString(R.string.x_minute_ago, minutes)
            }
            hours <= 24 -> when (hours) {
                1 -> context.getString(R.string.x_hour_ago, hours)
                else -> context.getString(R.string.x_hours_ago, hours)
            }
            days <= 7 -> when (days) {
                1 -> context.getString(R.string.yesterday)
                else -> context.getString(R.string.x_days_ago, days)
            }
            weeks <= 4.3 -> when (weeks) {
                1 -> context.getString(R.string.x_week_ago, weeks)
                else -> context.getString(R.string.x_weeks_ago, weeks)
            }
            months <= 12 -> when (months) {
                1 -> context.getString(R.string.x_month_ago, months)
                else -> context.getString(R.string.x_months_ago, months)
            }
            else -> when (years) {
                1 -> context.getString(R.string.x_year_ago, years)
                else -> context.getString(R.string.x_years_ago, years)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin:

```
import java.util.*

val Int.week: Period
    get() = Period(period = Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH, value = this)

internal val calendar: Calendar by lazy {
    Calendar.getInstance()
}

operator fun Date.minus(duration: Period): Date {
    calendar.time = this
    calendar.add(duration.period, -duration.value)
    return calendar.time
}

data class Period(val period: Int, val value: Int)
```

Usage:

```
val newDate = oldDate - 1.week
// Or val newDate = oldDate.minus(1.week)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Date getDateWithOffset(int offset, Date date){
    Calendar calendar = calendar = Calendar.getInstance();;
    calendar.setTime(date);
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, offset);
    return calendar.getTime();
}

Date weekAgoDate = getDateWithOffset(-7, new Date());
```

---

### OR using Joda:

add Joda library

```
    implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.10'
```

'

```
DateTime now = new DateTime();
DateTime weekAgo = now.minusWeeks(1);
Date weekAgoDate = weekAgo.toDate()// if you want to convert it to Date
```

### -----------------------------UPDATE-------------------------------

Use Java 8 APIs or ThreeTenABP for Android (minSdk<24).

ThreeTenABP:

```
implementation 'com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.2.1'
```

'

```
LocalDate now= LocalDate.now();
now.minusWeeks(1);
```

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

Comment: Using java.time is now possible on all APIs, Android gradle plugin in version [4.0.0](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#4-0-0) added support to [Java 8 library desugaring in D8 and R8](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#j8-library-desugaring).