# Get Date of past 7days from current in android

Tags: android

I am trying to fetch the date 7days prior to today's date.
I am using SimpleDateFormat to fetch today's date.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Please guide me through this

Updated answer which I found most useful

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
Date cdate=sdf.parse(currentDateandTime);
Calendar now2= Calendar.getInstance();
now2.add(Calendar.DATE, -7);
String beforedate=now2.get(Calendar.DATE)+"/"+(now2.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1)+"/"+now2.get(Calendar.YEAR);
Date BeforeDate1=sdf.parse(beforedate);
cdate.compareTo(BeforeDate1);
```

Thank you for you reply

Comment: Kindly accept the answer if you have got your solution ;)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use `java.util.Calendar`, set it to today's date and then subtract 7 days.

```
Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(new Date());
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -7);
Date 7daysBeforeDate = cal.getTime();
```

**Edit:** In Java 8 it can be done much easier by using classes from `java.time` package:

```
final LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
final LocalDate dateMinus7Days = date.minusDays(7);
//Format and display date
final String formattedDate = dateMinus7Days.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

Comment: probably should be cal.roll instead of cal.set?

Answer (score 5):

You can try out this,

```
import java.util.Calendar;

public class AddDaysToCurrentDate {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    //create Calendar instance
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

    System.out.println("Current date : " + (now.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1)
                        + "-"
                        + now.get(Calendar.DATE)
                        + "-"
                        + now.get(Calendar.YEAR));

    //add days to current date using Calendar.add method
    now.add(Calendar.DATE,1);

    System.out.println("date after one day : " + (now.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1)
                        + "-"
                        + now.get(Calendar.DATE)
                        + "-"
                        + now.get(Calendar.YEAR));


    //substract days from current date using Calendar.add method
    now = Calendar.getInstance();
    now.add(Calendar.DATE, -10);

    System.out.println("date before 10 days : " + (now.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1)
                        + "-"
                        + now.get(Calendar.DATE)
                        + "-"
                        + now.get(Calendar.YEAR));

  }
}

/*
Typical output would be
Current date : 12-25-2007
date after one day : 12-26-2007
date before 10 days : 12-15-2007
*/
```

Answer (score 3):

[Android get date before 7 days (one week)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747490/android-get-date-before-7-days-one-week)

```
Date myDate = dateFormat.parse(dateString);
```

And then either figure out how many milliseconds you need to subtract:

```
Date newDate = new Date(myDate.getTime() - 604800000L); // 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
```

Or use the API provided by the java.util.Calendar class:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(myDate);
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -7);
Date newDate = calendar.getTime();
Then, if you need to, convert it back to a String:
```

and finally

```
String date = dateFormat.format(newDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this kotlin function to get any date before the current date.

```
/**
 * get specific date before current date
 * [day] number of day
 * [month] number of month
 * [year] number of year
 * [count] number of day, month, year
 *
 * return date
 */
fun getBeforeDate(day: Boolean = false, month: Boolean = false, year: Boolean = false, count: Int = 0): String{

    val currentCalendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    val myFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"  // you can use your own date format
    val sdf = SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.getDefault())
    if (day){
        currentCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -count)
    }else if(month){
        currentCalendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -count)
    }else if(year){
        currentCalendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, -count)
    }else{
        // if user not provide any value then give current date
        currentCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 0)
        // or you can throw Exception
        //throw Exception("Please provide at least one value")
    }

    return sdf.format(currentCalendar.time)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fun getBeforeDate(day: Boolean = false, month: Boolean = false, year: Boolean = false, count: Int = 0): String{

    val currentCalendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    val myFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"  // you can use your own date format
    val sdf = SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.getDefault())
    if (day){
        currentCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -count)
    }else if(month){
        currentCalendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -count)
    }else if(year){
        currentCalendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, -count)
    }else{
        // if user not provide any value then give current date
        currentCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 0)
        // or you can throw Exception
        //throw Exception("Please provide at least one value")
    }

    return sdf.format(currentCalendar.time)
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).