# How to fetch recent seven days from specific date

Tags: android, simpledateformat

If the date is `2017-03-30` that i want to fetch the date from `2017-03-23` to `2017-03-30`

I try to use this code let my `String` change to `Date` format

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

Date dateParse = sdf.parse("2017-03-30");
```

then i'm stuck , cause i take the reference is get the current time like this

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.add(Calendar.DATE, -7);
//may be my dateParse should put here , but i don't know how to do
Date monday = c.getTime();//it get the current time
String preMonday = sdf.format(monday);
```

Is any one can teach me how to fetch these seven days ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse the date:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date myDate = sdf.parse("2017-03-30");
```

First Solution 1) And then either figure out how many milliseconds you need to subtract:

```
Date newDate = new Date(myDate.getTime() - 604800000L); // 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
```

Second Solution 2) Or use the API provided by the java.util.Calendar class:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(myDate);
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -7);
Date newDate = calendar.getTime();
```

Then, if you need to, convert it back to a String:

```
String date = dateFormat.format(newDate);
```

This answer is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3747561/7320259)

EDIT:
 If you need output as 2017-03-29 2017-03-28 2017-03-27 ...... 2017-03-23 then try below code

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 7; i++){
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(myDate);
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -i);
    Date newDate = calendar.getTime();
    String date = dateFormat.format(newDate);
    //here in date you can get all date from and output as 2017-03-29 2017-03-28 2017-03-27 ...... 2017-03-23
}
```

Hope you need this

Comment: thanks for your information , but i got confused about the variable newDate. There is two newDate , which the newDate use for `String date = dateFormat.format(newDate);` ?

Comment: I try the first newDate that the result date is `2017-03-23` , i just get a day , can i get seven days ?

Comment: check my edited answer bro. There is two solutions please check. If you get any problem please ask freely I will help you @徐博俊

Comment: you need all 7 days? What you need I can't understand properly

Comment: You need output as 2017-03-29 2017-03-28 2017-03-27 ...... 2017-03-23? or something else?

Comment: Yes , i want the values which is 2017-03-29 2017-03-28 2017-03-27 ...... 2017-03-23 , my reason is that i parse json and i want to set `if-else` for specific day

Comment: thanks you so much , the answer is more easier to understand now.

Comment: Happy to help you brother :) :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the code below

```
  SimpleDateFormatdateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
       String date = dateFormat.format(c.getTime());

  c.add(Calendar.DATE, 7);
        String date1 = dateFormat.format(c.getTime());
```

Comment: thanks man , but your code just like my question , the date is current date not my specific date.

Comment: This can help u get the current date                                                                                                                          
 String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());

Comment: thanks for your enthusiam , i get the solution now , thank you.