# How to get date 7 days ago to today in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to get date from 7 days ago to today in Kotlin. Any suggestions? This is what I have so far

```
val date = Calendar.getInstance()

val yesterday = Calendar.getInstance()

yesterday.add(Calendar.DATE,-1)

var todayOrYesterday:String?

var todayDate = date.time

while (todayDate > yesterday.time){

    val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, d MMMM yyyy")

    val format = formatter.format(todayDate)

    println(format)

    todayOrYesterday = if (DateUtils.isToday(date.timeInMillis)) {
            "Today"
    }else "Yesterday"

    date.add(Calendar.DATE,-7)
}
```

Comment: Write your output.

Comment: please can you check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This is a reference link for your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747490/android-get-date-before-7-days-one-week

Comment: This has been addressed many times already. Search Stack Overflow before posting.  Hints: `java.time.LocalDate.now().minusWeeks( 1 )`, *ThreeTen-Backport*, *ThreeTenABP*.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Use this function, pass the days ago you want:

```
fun getDaysAgo(daysAgo: Int): Date {
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -daysAgo)

    return calendar.time
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Simply use,

```
val date = Calendar.getInstance()   // 19-01-2018
date.add(Calendar.DATE, -7)         // 12-01-2018
```

Comment: This troublesome old Class is now legacy, supplanted by the *java.time* classes. For older Android see the ThreeTen-Backport and ThreeTenABP projects.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use [Joda Time](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time) ([Joda Time for Android](https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android)). This library has a really nice API.

```
DateTime.now().minusDays(7)
```

And you can call `.toDate()` if you need a Java-Date object.

Link: [Why Joda Time?](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/#Why_Joda-Time)

Comment: The Joda-Time project is now in maintenance mode, with the team advising migration to the *java.time* classes. For earlier Android see the *ThreeTen-Backport* and *ThreeTenABP* projects.